# Sending locally sent email (with sendmail) to Google Apps Mail Server

Tags: email, localhost, sendmail

I have a domain, call it mydom.com.
A while ago I started using Google App's email server. I set up MX and the rest of the stuff records as Google wanted, and all is working well since.

On www.mydom.com I have a website, DNS and still running mail server (which basically doesn't do much).
Among other things, on www.mydom.com, I have some contact form - basic php page that takes user's input and sends it to predefined email address at mydom.com. It sends it with php's sendmail function.

My issue is - all those email that get sent from localhost to *@mydom.com (by php's function, or possible by some cron jobs reporting some issues) DO NOT go to Google's email servers but instead get picked up by localhost and it's mail server.

So far, I was resolving this issue by setting up a new mail account at Google account, which was basically calling my local mail server by it's IP address, logging into old, abandoned email account and pulling those misplaced emails to the new, @mydom.com account at Google App.

Obviously I'm missing some entry either in local DNS, host file or something.. 
Does anyone know how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you switch of the mail functionality on your server for this domain? That solved my problem.

Comment: Tnx Tim,
I might - but wouldn't that remove the whole sendmail functionality for the website? So then I wouldn't get ANY emails sent locally from my localhost to my domain, that is - wouldn't PHP throw an error in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, the same question was asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/102647/sendmail-to-local-domain-ignoring-mx-records-part-2

and the answer to it works for me, don't forget to include the dot after the domain!

If it doesn't work to the test call and see how the mail traces.

best of luck, svullo